# BaseAdapter notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't update object reference

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I have to refresh my listview every 3 seconds (I'm in ListFragment) so I start a new Thread wich start runOnUiThread to edit UI.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            do{
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                VideoData element = null;
                try {
                    element = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://192.168.4.111:3232/videodata.json").openStream(), VideoData.class);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final VideoData newData = element;
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        hd = newData.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(id);
                        vba.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3*1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }while(true);   
        }
    }).start();
    setAdapter();
}
```

I parse data on web, and update the reference.

```
private void setAdapter()
{
    if(id == 0)
        hd = hd.getChildren().get(0);
    vba = new ValueBaseAdapter(getActivity(), 0, hd.getChildren());
    setListAdapter(vba);
}
```

I saw that when notifyDataSetChanged is called, getView is called (and it's ok) but I have old reference, the one of when I called setAdapter the first time.
Also If I set null hd in run(), doesn't change anything, listview doesn't change.
Where is the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that notifyDataSetChanged() updates adapter's data only if you work with List